# Error-checking for command line arguments

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, command-line-arguments

For my program, I'm having issues creating a error check if the user does not enter the commandline arguments and display an error message. Instead of crashing.
With no text file argument, I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :o ?

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArgument) {
      Integer[] array = ReadFile7.readFileReturnIntegers(commandlineArgument[0]);
      ReadFile7.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, commandlineArgument[0]);
      if(commandlineArgument.length == 0){
         System.out.println("Please file name " +
               "as the first commandline argument.");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Just move 'if(commandlineArgument.length == 0){...' block to the top of main method. And add 'return 1;' inside if block to stop execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just check:

```
if(commandlineArgument.length == 0){ ... }
```

before using:

```
commandlineArgument[0]
```

Comment: Oh gosh, of course o___o... Can't believe I messed that up. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's far from perfect, but for command-line APIs, I´ve been using a lot commons-cli: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Just check **first** if `commandlineArgument` is greater than 0:

```
if (commandlineArgument.length == 0){
    System.out.println("Please enter the file name " +
        "as the 1st commandline argument.");
} else {
    Integer[] array = ReadFile7.readFileReturnIntegers(commandlineArgument[0]);
    ReadFile7.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, commandlineArgument[0]);
}
```